# How to force EXPR instead of GLOB dereference?

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub XX { 30 };

my $rnd =  3;
my $z =  -XX * $rnd;
```

Give error:   `Can't use string ("3") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use`

This does not help:

```
my $z =  -XX * ($rnd);
```

I get next error:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at game4.pl line 7, near "* ($rnd"
    (Missing operator before $rnd?)
syntax error at game4.pl line 7, near "* ($rnd"
Execution of game4.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

**How to force `EXPR` instead of `GLOB` dereference?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few options.

Explicitly tell Perl that you're not passing parameters to `XX`.

```
my $z =  -XX() * $rnd;
```

Use the old-style calling conventions for subroutines (I really don't recommend this one).

```
my $z =  -&XX * $rnd;
```

Define the subroutine as not taking parameters.

```
sub XX() { 30 };
```

But the best solution is to use the built-in [`constant`](https://metacpan.org/pod/constant) pragma.

```
use constant XX => 30;
```